# Someone who wants everything to be even

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that would describe someone's behaviour or personality which says that they enjoy it when things are fair. So, for example, when they win money as part of a team, they would be happiest if every member got the same amount, or if they were splitting a cake they would be happiest if everyone got the same size.

I've thought of altruist, communist, etc. but these don't quite describe what I'm looking for.

Comment: egalitarian or socialist, the first being more suitable for non-political personality observation.  maybe a populist or, more anglo-saxon and less political, a leveller

Comment: Would [*maples*](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/r/rush/the+trees_20119968.html) be the sort of thing you’re looking for here?

Comment: Thanks JamesHH! These are all useful to keep in mind! And it would appear so tchrist, that seems to relate to my situation quite well!

Comment: "Steven", named after the same fellow we reference with "even stevens". Can be used as "He's a Steven", or "oh stop being such a Steven". (yes I just made this up.... I think...)

Comment: A single word for “someone who wants everything to be even”: [imparnumerophobic](http://phobia.wikia.com/wiki/Imparnumerophobia)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Egalitarian**:

> adjective 1.  of, relating to, or upholding the doctrine of the
>   equality of mankind and the desirability of political, social, and
>   economic equality
>
> noun 2. **an adherent of egalitarian principles**
>
> ... her strength is the direct product of egalitarian
>   Scandinavian society, where gender roles are merged rather than
>   sharply defined.
>
> ([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/egalitarian))

Comment: Yes this is what I'm looking for I think! Thank you very much for the help, and you've added another word to my vocabulary!

Answer (score 5):

Well, seeing as [a synonym of "even" is "level"](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/even), perhaps you could use the word **[leveller](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leveller)**:

> 1. a person or thing that levels
> 2. a person who works for the abolition of inequalities

<sup>Collins English Dictionary</sup>

Note that the use of this word in your mentioned situations isn't established usage. As Michael Seifart points out in a comment, definition number 2 stems from a [17th-century English social movement by that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levellers).

Comment: This has more of a connotation of "working for equality through the political process";  sense #2 of the word stems from a [17th-century English social movement by that name.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levellers)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - Thanks. I really should have included that already! Edited in, borrowing your wording with attribution :)

Answer (score 3):

Equitable

> adjective: 
>   1. characterized by equity or fairness; just and right; fair; reasonable:
>   equitable treatment of all citizens.

example:

> She is a very equitable person in all aspects of her life.